# Remove specific elements with xslt based on value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Using xslt, I want to remove the all of the `part` elements that do not have a `partid` equal to the one that is a child of `<RtoP>`.

```
<tran>
<part>
<Partid>123
</Partid>
</part>
<part>
<Partid>200
</Partid>
</part>
<part>
<Partid>777
</Partid>
</part>
<refs>
<RtoP>
<partid>200</partid>
</RtoP>
</refs>
</tran>
```

So that the result is

```
<tran>
<part>
<Partid>200
</Partid>
</part>
<refs>
<RtoP>
<partid>200</partid>
</RtoP>
<refs>
</tran>
```

Please assist with how to do this in an xslt.

Comment: Must use xlst 1.0

Comment: Try starting with an [identity transform](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying) and add an empty template matching `part[normalize-space(Partid)=normalize-space(/tran/refs/RtoP/partid)]`

Comment: Daniel, I'm getting an error message saying there is an expected token ')' - not sure what to do. Please advise.

Comment: You should add your XSLT to your question so we can help you debug. ([Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: Also, your example output seems to be the exact opposite of what you're requesting. Do you want to remove `part` elements that have a value that matches a child of `RtoP` or do you want to delete `part` elements that do not have a value that matches a child of `RtoP`?

Comment: Sorry I want to remove the Parts that don't equal the child of RToP. Anyway here is my xlst:

Comment: ['code'] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="part[normalize-space(Partid)=normalize-space(/tran/refs/RtoP‌​/partid)]"></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Can you add your XSLT to your question by clicking "edit" at the bottom of the question? There are issues in your XSLT that I'm not sure are because of the code being in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try starting with an identity template and add an empty template that matches `part` elements that don't equal a `partid` child of `RtoP`...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template 
    match="part[normalize-space(Partid) != normalize-space(/tran/refs/RtoP/partid)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If there could be multiple `RtoP` elements, or multiple children of `RtoP`, consider using an [xsl:key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#key)...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="keep" match="RtoP/*" use="normalize-space()"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="part[not(key('keep',normalize-space()))]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT**: Latest input/xslt/output examples from http://xsltransform.net/93dEHG6/8

**Input**

```
<my:TRAN xmlns:my="himom" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <my:DAY>
    <my:LANE>
      <my:LANEID>900</my:LANEID>
    </my:LANE>
    <my:COT>
      <my:place>
        <my:PR>
          <my:RID>253503</my:RID>
        </my:PR>
        <my:Acreage>0</my:Acreage>
        <my:City>Mars</my:City>
      </my:place>
      <my:COTID>31263</my:COTID>
    </my:COT>
     <my:PART>
       <my:PARTId>123</my:PARTId>
     </my:PART>
    <my:PART>
      <my:PARTId>200</my:PARTId>
    </my:PART>
    <my:PART>
      <my:PARTId>777</my:PARTId>
    </my:PART>
    <my:REFERENCES>
      <my:RToP>
        <my:RID>253503</my:RID>
        <my:PARTId>200</my:PARTId>
        <my:PARTRoleType>B</my:PARTRoleType>
      </my:RToP>
      <my:RToP>
        <my:RID>253503</my:RID>
        <my:PARTId>134175</my:PARTId>
        <my:PARTRoleType>I</my:PARTRoleType>
      </my:RToP>
      <my:RToP>
        <my:RID>253503</my:RID>
        <my:PARTId>777</my:PARTId>
        <my:PARTRoleType>R</my:PARTRoleType>
      </my:RToP>
      <my:RToP>
        <my:RID>253503</my:RID>
        <my:PARTId>121871</my:PARTId>
        <my:PARTRoleType>S</my:PARTRoleType>
      </my:RToP>
      <my:RToP>
        <my:RID>253503</my:RID>
        <my:PARTId>87372</my:PARTId>
        <my:PARTRoleType>IC</my:PARTRoleType>
      </my:RToP>
        <my:RToP>
        <my:RID>253504</my:RID>
        <my:PARTId>123</my:PARTId>
        <my:PARTRoleType>IC</my:PARTRoleType>
      </my:RToP>
    </my:REFERENCES>
    <my:DAYIdentifier />
  </my:DAY>
</my:TRAN>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:my="himom">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="keep" 
    match="my:RToP[normalize-space(my:RID) = normalize-space(/my:TRAN/my:DAY/my:COT/my:place/my:PR/my:RID)]" 
    use="normalize-space(my:PARTId)"/>  

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="my:RToP[normalize-space(my:RID) != normalize-space(/my:TRAN/my:DAY/my:COT/my:place/my:PR/my:RID)]"/>

  <xsl:template match="my:PART[not(key('keep',normalize-space(my:PARTId)))]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<my:TRAN xmlns:my="himom" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <my:DAY>
      <my:LANE>
         <my:LANEID>900</my:LANEID>
      </my:LANE>
      <my:COT>
         <my:place>
            <my:PR>
               <my:RID>253503</my:RID>
            </my:PR>
            <my:Acreage>0</my:Acreage>
            <my:City>Mars</my:City>
         </my:place>
         <my:COTID>31263</my:COTID>
      </my:COT>
      <my:PART>
         <my:PARTId>200</my:PARTId>
      </my:PART>
      <my:PART>
         <my:PARTId>777</my:PARTId>
      </my:PART>
      <my:REFERENCES>
         <my:RToP>
            <my:RID>253503</my:RID>
            <my:PARTId>200</my:PARTId>
            <my:PARTRoleType>B</my:PARTRoleType>
         </my:RToP>
         <my:RToP>
            <my:RID>253503</my:RID>
            <my:PARTId>134175</my:PARTId>
            <my:PARTRoleType>I</my:PARTRoleType>
         </my:RToP>
         <my:RToP>
            <my:RID>253503</my:RID>
            <my:PARTId>777</my:PARTId>
            <my:PARTRoleType>R</my:PARTRoleType>
         </my:RToP>
         <my:RToP>
            <my:RID>253503</my:RID>
            <my:PARTId>121871</my:PARTId>
            <my:PARTRoleType>S</my:PARTRoleType>
         </my:RToP>
         <my:RToP>
            <my:RID>253503</my:RID>
            <my:PARTId>87372</my:PARTId>
            <my:PARTRoleType>IC</my:PARTRoleType>
         </my:RToP>
      </my:REFERENCES>
      <my:DAYIdentifier/>
   </my:DAY>
</my:TRAN>
```

Comment: I looked at the second part of your post, and tried using the xsl:key as only my first PART was retained. Using the key method, however, all of the PART elements are retained which is not expected. Please advise. I have multiple RtoP elements with of different PARTID inside, related to different PART elements.

Comment: @Ober - Can you update your question with another example?

Comment: `code` <tran>
<part>
<Partid>123
</Partid>
</part>
<part>
<Partid>200
</Partid>
</part>
<part>
<Partid>777
</Partid>
</part>
<refs>
<RtoP>
<Rid>5</Rid>
<partid>200</partid>
</RtoP><RtoP><Rid>5</Rid>
<partid>777</partid>
</RtoP>
</refs>
</tran>

Comment: sorry the code above may be hard to read. From the xml above, I would expect the part containing partid 123 to disappear because there are no RtoP elements with that partid in it. However, parts containing partid of 200 and 777 should remain.

Comment: @Ober - Seems to work for me: http://xsltransform.net/93dEHG6 Although you might want to change the match in the xsl:key to `match="RtoP/partid"` so parts aren't removed based on `Rid` values.

Comment: Here is a better example I think.  http://xsltransform.net/93dEHG6/3.  Same requirements  - I expect PART with the PartID of 123 to be removed. Please advise.

Comment: I see how your solution works. However in the actual XLST I need to first clean out all RtoP that do not have a RID equal to the PR/RID above. I can't get both to work. I have only been successful running your transform in version 4 after I do my cleaning in a separate xlst. Please advise how to do this in one xlst. thanks http://xsltransform.net/93dEHG6/7

Comment: @Ober - Here's my latest and final change. If you still have issues, please create a new question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). http://xsltransform.net/93dEHG6/8

Comment: You don't have that code handy do you? The xsltransform site is down.

Comment: @Ober - I edited my answer on July 13th for that very reason. (see the code below `EDIT: Latest input/xslt/output examples from http://xsltransform.net/93dEHG6/8` in my answer)